# File upload using jquery works in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

This javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
                element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
                action: 'api/GradeCheckIn',
                debug: true,
                onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                    alert(responseJSON[0].ValidationErrors[0].ErrorMessage);
                }
            });
        });
```

works like a charm in Firefox. The file is posted to the server and the result is returned to the client. The data returned is json btw.

But in Internet Explorer I get the message **Do you want to open or save GradeCheckIn (2 bytes) from localhost.** like I'm trying to download a file.

How can I solve this? I want the same behaviour in Explorer as in Firefox.

**Edit after comments:**

The content-type in the request header differs between IE and FireFox:

```
IE: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7dc2ec8205b2

Firefox: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

This is even though I explicitly set the content-type in the code where the request is made:

```
xhr.open("POST", queryString, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", encodeURIComponent(name));
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
xhr.send(file);
```

I still can't solve this. All ideas are highly appreciated. Please let me know if I should provide more information.

Comment: It sounds like the response you are sending from your server is sending back an unrecognized mime type to the hidden iframe. What mime type is it returning?

Comment: @Tejs I provided information about content-type in the question above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most browsers dont handle `application/json` as the return content type. If you want to still write the json and read it out of the iframe, you might just consider 'hacking' the response and send back your content, but with the mime type of `text/html`.